# Can I just broadcast a specific message in my own network in python?

Tags: python

I just want to broadcast a udp message on a specific port on my network. How can I accomplish this in python?

Answer (score 5):

This will only work with IPv4 networks:

```
BC_PORT = 12345
import sys, time
from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('', 0))
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.sendto("hello world", ('<broadcast>', BC_PORT))
```

Comment: and how about if i want my program to run on ipv6?